# Access to fetch at 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I keep getting this in my console and i don't understand, please can somebody help me and explain.
Access to fetch at 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: What request are you making? A simple GET shouldn't need any CORS handling. Give a [mre]. `fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4').then((res) => res.json()).then((body) => console.log(body))` works as expected in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

In your api domain `https://randomuser.me`, add `localhost` to your list of allowed origin.

The reason you're getting this error is because `https://randomuser.me` expects request from origin `https://randomuser.me` and not from some other sources like from your `localhost`. If this is not satisfied it will be returned as a warning/error by your browser.

Answer (score -1):

To be able to allow API Proxy within a react app - You need to edit the package.json with the following

```
"proxy": "https://randomuser.me",
```

More details can be found on the create-react-dev [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)